# Find $Ker(df_p)$ of the differential on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M=\mathbb{R}^2 , N=\mathbb{R}^3$ differentiable manifolds and $f:M \rightarrow N$ : $f(x,y)= (x,y^3,x^4)$ is obviously differnetiable.
For $p=(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $v \in T_{p}\mathbb{R}^2$ we define: 
Let $c:(-\epsilon , \epsilon ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $c(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ be a curve s.t. $c(0)=p,c'(0)=v$ and $\bar{c}(t)=f\circ c $

The differential is:
$df_p:T_{p}\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}^3$:
with $df_{p}(v)=\bar{c}'(0)$

Now we compute $\bar{c}'(0)$:
$\bar{c}(t)=f(c(t))= (x(t),y^3(t),x^4(t))$
$\bar{c}'(t)=(f(c(t)))'= (x'(t),3y^2(t)y'(t),4x^3(t)x'(t)$
$\bar{c}'(0)=(f(c(0)))'= (x'(0),3y^2(0)y'(0),4x^3(0)x'(0)$

**For the Kernal:**
I know that $Ker(df_p)= \{ v\in T_{p}\mathbb{R}^2 : df_{p}(v)=0 \} $ \
but how do i find these vectors $v$ that are in the $Ker(df_p)$ if i don't know specifically the curve $c(t)$.

And if someone has a link that has some detailed explanation of the kernal of the differential.
Thanks!

**Update:**
For $c(t)=p+tv=(x,y)+t(v_1,v_2)$ after some calculations i find:
$df_{p}(v)=\bar{c}'(0)=(xv_1+yv_2,v_1,v_2,2yv_2)$

$(xv_1+yv_2,v_1,v_2,2yv_2)=0 \Rightarrow $
$v_1=0$ , $v_2=0$ 

So $Ker(df_p)=\{0\}$?

Comment: In any dimension, $T_p\Bbb R^n$ is **canonically** isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. If you really want to use the path-definition, you can assign to $v\in \Bbb R^2$ the curve $\gamma\colon t\mapsto p+tv$. Then, you just have to determine the kernel of a usual linear map between $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Didier Updated!

Comment: What you wrote is nonsense: according to you, $d_pf(v)$ has four coordinates. Recall that it should be in $\Bbb R^3$...

Comment: The pushforward is just the Jacobian matrix in coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Write $p=(x,y)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2)$.
Consider $\gamma(t) = p+tv$.
Then $f(\gamma(t)) = \left(x+tv_1,(y+tv_2)^3, (x+tv_1)^4\right)$.
By definition, $d_pf(v) = \left.\frac{d f(\gamma(t))}{dt}\right|_{t=0}$, and some very basis calculus yields
$$
d_pf(v) = (v_1,3y^2v_2,4x^3v_1).
$$
It is more convenient to look at the matrix of $d_pf$ in the canonical bases, which is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 3y^2 \\
4x^3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Can you go on from there?

Comment: For $d_pf(v) = (v_1,3y^2v_2,4x^3v_1)=0 \Rightarrow (v_1,v_2)=(0,0),$ so $ker(df_p)=\{0\}$?

Comment: @lebong66 No: what if $y=0$ for instance?

Comment: I’m sorry I can’t understand what is the kernel can you please explain

Comment: @lebong66 The matrix you get represents the pushforward at a certain point $p$ depending on $x$ and $y$. Thus for each fixed $p$ you can calculate the kernel as you would for any other linear transformation, eg by finding the null space of the matrix. Note the answer will in general also depend on $x$ and $y$.